# Shiny Reactable highlight selected cell speed

Tags: r, shiny, reactable

It's possible to conditionally format a selected cell in Reactable's shiny framework by setting two input$ values to the selected cell's data but in the comparison function to then change the format of this cell, it can take a very long time for large tables.

This is likely because the way I'm going about it is searching the whole table for something that matches the input$ values. Is there a more speed efficient way to do this? You can try by running this first and then uncommenting out the replication function and seeing how much slower it becomes.

```
library(shiny)
library(reactable)

data <- MASS::road[11:17, ]
data <- tibble::rownames_to_column(data, "state")

#data <- do.call("rbind", replicate(100, data, simplify = FALSE))

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("reactable example"),
  reactableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- renderReactable({
    
    reactable(
      data,
      defaultColDef = colDef(
        style = function(value, index, name) {
          if (!is.null(input$col)) {
            print(paste0("Col: ", input$col$index))
            print(paste0("Row: ", input$row$index))
            print(paste0("Index: ", index))
            print(paste0("Name: ", name))
            print(paste0("Value: ", value))
            if (input$col$index == name &&
                input$row$index == data[index, "state"]) {
              list(fontWeight = "bold")
            }
          }
        }
      ),
      onClick = JS("function(rowInfo, column) {
                            if (window.Shiny) {
                              Shiny.setInputValue('row', {index: rowInfo.values.state})
                              Shiny.setInputValue('col', {index: column.name})
                            }
                          }"),
    )
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71152385/9841389) you can find a related answer using JS (link in the comment below the answer). Please also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72768938/reactable-r-shiny-conditional-color-columns-on-updatedata/72769693#72769693) on how to combine R+JS code.